# Fill with values - dynamic dropdowns

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to fill dropdowns with values while dropdowns are "sent" trough props. I'm getting the data from server correctly, and storing it in array where I am using that array to fill selected dropdown.
This problem looks like its Vuetify or Vue bug but I'm not sure.

Code for dynamic dropdowns looks like this (Vuetify):

```js
    <v-col cols="12" lg="2" md="2" sm="6" xs="6" v-for="(dropdowns, index) in dropdownNumber" v-bind:key="index">

            <v-select
            :v-model="dropdowns.field_name"
            :loading="loadingInputs"
            :label="dropdowns.dropdown_name"
            :disabled="enableDropdowns"

            :items="getData[dropdowns.field_name]"
            :clearable="true"
     
            :item-text="dropdowns.field_name"
            :item-value="dropdowns.field_name"
            :item-key="dropdowns.field_name"
            @mousedown="changeFields(dropdowns.field_name, index)"
            @change="selectedValue(dropdowns.field_name, $event)"
            :multiple="dropdowns.multiple"
          >
           
          </v-select>
```

And function for take data from server:

```js
    async getDropdownData($event, index) {
        
          const key = $event
          

         try {
          
          this.values['sector_name'] = this.categoryName()
          this.keys.forEach(element => {
            if(localStorage.getItem(element) != null) {
              this.values[element] = localStorage.getItem(element)
            } 
          });
  

  
          this.takeServerData = (await DataService.getDropdownData({
              existingValues: this.values,
              selectedDropdown: $event
          })).data 
          
          this.getData[key] = this.takeServerData
          

          console.log(this.getData)

         
         } catch (error) {
           this.error = "Dogodila se pogreška prilikom dohvaćanja vrijednosti za tu opciju."
         }
      },
```

Sometimes, while I'm editing my code it normally fill already clicked dropdown, but after refreshing site it does not work.

Photo example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3j6N.jpg

Is there something I'm missing?

Any help or advice is welcome!

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using the `v-select` component properly. Should be `:options` not `:items` according to the usage example: https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select

Comment: @Crayons sorry, I did not mention here, I'm using Vuetify dropdown: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/

Comment: ¿Do you have any error on your log? Have you run lint?

Comment: @eyyo yes I did.. No errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a reactivity problem related to nested objects.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Either sure your arrays are predefined within the getData object.

```
data () {
    return {
      getData: {
         field1 : [],
         field2 : []
      }
  }
},
```

Or update your getData object like this

```
this.$set(this.getData, key, this.takeServerData)
```